# Typescript with --strictNullCheck - check not null in separate method

Tags: typescript, strictnullchecks

I am having fun with the compiler **--strictNullCheck** option

I have this method:

[image]

[image]

I **need** to check if the headers are not null before i can use them. That's great

Now I would like to move the checking operation to the **separate** method like this:

[image]

But not I'm getting this error:

[image]

So there is no way to check if some object or the some of its property is not null in the separate method?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a type guard. A type guard is some expression that performs a runtime check that guarantees the type in some scope.

In your case something like this may work (its hard to tell since you pasted images instead of code):

```
function hasHeaders(error: Response): error is Response & { headers: Headers} {
    return error.headers != null
}
```

You can learn more about type guards in typescript handbook at https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html

Answer (score -1):

It should be pretty simple:

```
if(err.headers != null) {
  return error.headers.get('content-type') || defaultContentType;
} else {
  return defaultContentType; // or whatever
}
```

You could also put that in your `hasHeaders` code, however, the typescript compiler may or may not still throw that warning.

A couple more details about checking for nulls though:

### Checking values via their 'truthy' value

You can just check if the value is "truthy", i.e. it is not `null`, `undefined`, `0`, `false`, or `''` by using the value as a boolean, i.e. `if (value) { /* do something */ }` or `return value || defaultValue` or `return value ? value : defaultValue`, etc.

In this way you can do something like this:

```
return error.headers ?
    (error.headers.get('content-type') || defaultContentType) : 
    defaultContentType /* or whatever */;
```

Though that can be a little messy if your variable names are long.

### Using identify vs equality checks

Some people prefer to use `===` (and `!==`) (identity) instead of `==` (and `!=`) (equality), because `===` is a stricter check; however, `null == undefined` is equal to true, whereas `null === undefined` is equal to false, so use the correct one in the correct place!